# create <div> for each word in value=""

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#values').html('<div>'+value+'</div>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text'>
<div>

</div>
```

In this code, Im trying to let the user type some words like **`Hello World, This Is My Home`** inside the `input`, Now the thing i want to happen is for each word, it will make a `div` for it inside the **parent** empty `div`,
So for my example here the result i want supposed to be

```js
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#values').html('<div>'+value+'</div>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' value='Hello World, This Is My Home'>
    <div id='values'>
        <div>Hello</div>
        <div>World</div>
        <div>This</div>
        <div>Is</div>
        <div>My</div>
        <div>Home</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're appending the content, instead of replacing it. Try to use `.html()` instead of `.append()`

Comment: You could use the [`split` function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Comment: `$('div')` means `select all the <div> in the page`... including the ones you have created with the previous keystroke. So keystroke 1 creates a div, keystroke 2 selects 2 divs and creates 2 more, keystroke 3 selects 8 divs and creates 8 more... this is dangerously exponential. Give your initial div an ID and select only this one.

Comment: @JeremyThille Will fix that now With @dlopez `.html()` instead of `.append()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to split the words in input value string and then append div for each words separately. Also each time you append words you can first empty the div. 
`split(/[\s,]+/)` will split the string for delimiters space and comma. you can use an id for main container. the second argument to callback function in forEach is index, so you can use that to attach index if you want.

```js
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    var words = value.split(/[\s,]+/);
    $('#maindiv').html("");
    words.forEach((x, index) => $('#maindiv').append('<div>'+x + '-' + (index+1) +'</div>'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' value='Hello World, This Is My Home'>
    <div id="maindiv">
    </div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the word order number? like `Hello-1 World-2`? Or would it require to make an array and on and on?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your function is it always appends to all divs. 
so I have added a class name to one dive so each word is added to that Div.

Also your event is run every time a user presses any key. so i added a `if` to allow the user to hit the enter key to run the function

```
 $('input').keyup(function(e){

   // to check for enter keypress
   if(e.which==13){// 32 for space bar if you perfer
      var value = $(this).val();
      $('.Container').append('<div>'+value+'</div>');
   }
})


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text'>
<div class="Container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input').keyup(function(){
    
    var wrap = $('div.hello');
    wrap.empty();
    
    var array = $(this).val().split(" ");
    array.forEach(function(element){
        wrap.append('<div>'+element.replace(',', '')+'</div>');
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' value='Hello World, This Is My Home'>

<div class="hello"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `split` method.

Also, you have to use an `id` attribute for `main` div in order avoid `duplicate` div.

In this case you will see `2^n` words rendered.

```js
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var values = $(this).val().split(' ');
    $('#main').empty();
    values.forEach(function(word){
       $('#main').append('<div>'+word+'</div>');
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text'>
<div id="main">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the parent div before adding new elements; be very wary of using `.html()` to avoid script injections:

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
   var html = $(this).val().replace(/(\w+)/g, '<div>$1</div>')
   $('div').html('');
   $('#values').append(html);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('div')` means `select all the <div> in the page`... including the ones you have created with the previous keystroke. So keystroke 1 creates a div, keystroke 2 selects 2 divs and creates 2 more, keystroke 3 selects 8 divs and creates 8 more... this is dangerously exponential. Give your initial div an ID and select only this one.

Optimizations :

- Cache your jQuery objects and reuse them, instead of seeking the DOM and building new jQuery objects at each keystroke
- `e.target.value` is much faster than getting `$(this).val()`

```js
const $container = $("#container")

$('input').keyup( e => {
    $container.empty()
    e.target.value.trim().split(" ").forEach( word => {
      $container.append(`<span class="word">${word} </span>`);
    })
})
```

```css
.word {
   border : blue solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' value=''>
<div id="container"></div>
```